# How to get python dataframe column name using filter

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have imported one csv file to data frame & it has some 250+ columns and last column name starts with 'Unnamed:***' & some digit attached to it like "Unnamed: 1272"

I want to get that column name which starts 'Unnamed'. Below script didn't help.

```
dfColumns = pd.DataFrame(data.columns, columns=['columnName'])
UnnamedColumnName = str(dfColumns.loc[dfColumns['columnName'].str.contains('Unnamed')])
```

Result: '         columnName\n1272  Unnamed: 1272'

Below script also tried but no use:

```
data.columns.str.contains('Unnamed')
```

Expected results in 'Unnamed: 1272' in string variable "UnnamedColumnName", I want use this variable in delete columns script.

Comment: Are you sure that the last column is not named, rather that your first column is an unnamed index? e.g. if you did `df = pd.read_csv(my_csv, index_col=False)` may correct this

Comment: Please tag future pandas questions - python + pandas + dataframe (optional).

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, ok noted, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's always the last column you can just do

```
last_col = df.columns[-1]
```

You can also rename this using `rename`:

```
df = df.rename(columns={'new_name':df.columns[-1]})
```

Also `str.contains` returns you a boolean mask of the columns that match the string, you need to use this mask against the columns array:

```
data.columns[data.columns.str.contains('Unnamed')]
```

will return you an array with all columns where the boolean condition is met